# Common Table Expression - how to use result in PostGIS Function

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to use the result (`foo`) of a CTE as a function parameter (`foo.geom`) in a PostGIS funtion (`ST_DWithin()`).

```
WITH foo AS (
    SELECT geom FROM bar WHERE name = 'cat'
) SELECT name FROM whatever
    WHERE ST_DWithin( 
            geom,
            foo.geom,
            10
    );
```

I get

> Missing entry in FROM for table foo

And it highlights `foo.geom`.
Why is that? How would I use the result of

```
SELECT geom FROM bar WHERE name = 'cat'
```

in the query

```
SELECT name FROM whatever
    WHERE ST_DWithin( 
            geom,
            POINT(lng lat),
            10
    );
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to join `foo` in your main `select` statement's `from` clause in order for it's columns to be visible in the `where` clause.

It *looks* like you're expecting a single row in the `foo` CTE, so I expect you'd use a `cross` or `lateral` join.

```sql
WITH foo AS (
    SELECT geom FROM bar WHERE name = 'cat'
)
SELECT name
FROM whatever
     cross join foo
WHERE ST_DWithin( 
            geom,
            foo.geom,
            10
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `foo` CTE was not referenced in the main query. My guess is you want to join with it.

---

```
WITH foo AS (
    SELECT geom FROM bar WHERE name = 'cat'
) 
SELECT we.name
FROM whatever we
JOIN foo ON (ST_DWithin( we.geom, foo.geom, 10))
        ;
```